# Graphing non linear equation of two variables in RStudio

Tags: r, solver

I want to graph 0.2*ln(x/40)-0.02(x-40)=-0.04ln(y/100)+0.004(y-100) in RStudio. I installed 'manipulate' package and used plotFun but it didnt work. I tried using plot.function but I couldnt find a solution. please help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you've tried since you didn't provide any code. Perhaps this helps: Solve your equation for z (or set it = 0), then give `plotFun` your new expression:

```
library(manipulate)
library(mosaic)

plotFun(0.2*log(x/40)- 0.02*(x-40) + 0.04*log(y/100) - 0.004*(y-100) ~ 
        y+x, surface=TRUE, ylim=c(0,5), xlim=c(0,5))
```

If you just want for z=0, you can use `contour`:

```
xyFun <- function(x,y){
  0.2*log(x/40)- 0.02*(x-40)+0.04*log(y/100) - 0.004*(y-100)
}

x <- y <- seq(0,5, by=0.1)    
z <- outer(x,y,xyFun)

contour(x,y,z, levels=0)
```

or just

```
contour(x,y,z)
```